# Animating the Font Awesome battery icon

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome, battery

this is my first post. My question is simple : the same way you can easily animate a cog by adding the appropriate code in its class, is there a simple way to animate battery icons from empty to full?

Comment: I'm surprised that my post received a -1. What is not clear in my post? It's a rather simple question : class codes allow to animate some icons. I wondered if battery icons could be self-animated by a class code. It seems the answer is no. Thanks to lokesh who took some time to propose an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fa-stack` to overlap two font-awesome icons. But you have to manually create a animation for that. For animated battery you can try this,

```
  <span class="battery">
    <i class="fa fa-battery-empty"></i> 
    <i class="fa fa-battery-4 animate"></i>
  </span>
```

and some styles,

```
.battery{
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  color:#444;
}


.battery .animate{
  width:0%; 
  position:absolute;
  left: 0; 
  top:3px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  color:#27ae60;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.battery:hover .animate{
  width:100%;
}
```

Here's the demo, http://jsbin.com/foruyez/edit?html,css,output

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks lokesh. Not exactly what I hoped for but it may be useful anyway.